# How to create a new string from a given string, removing the first and last characters of the string if the first or last character are 'P'?

Tags: javascript, string, substring, comparison, indexof

I have to create a program creates a new string from a given string, removing the first and last characters of the string if the first or last character are 'P'. Then return the original string if the condition is not satisfied.
The code I wrote does not throw an error, but clearly the **if** condition is wrong since the code is always returning only the **str**. Could someone clarify what's the issue?

```
function remove(str) {
if (str.indexOf(0) === "p" && str.indexOf(-1) === "p") {
return str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
} else {
return str;
}
}

console.log(remove("pparallelepipedp"));
```

Comment: The OP seems to not have read the documentation of [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). Of cause neither of the conditions `'pparallelepipedp'.indexOf(0) === "p"` and `'pparallelepipedp'.indexOf(-1) === "p"` will ever fulfill.

Comment: If you have a condition that never works as you expect, that's the time to refer to the documentation.

Comment: @Florence116 ... The OP might try [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt), maybe even  [`at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/at) (where the latter supports the `-1` parameter value) instead.

Comment: @PeterSeliger no. Thank you for your support ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my above comments ...

> *"The OP seems to not have read the documentation of [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). Of cause neither of the conditions `'pparallelepipedp'.indexOf(0) === "p"` and `'pparallelepipedp'.indexOf(-1) === "p"` will ever fulfill."*

> *"... The OP might try [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt), maybe even  [`at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/at) (where the latter supports the `-1` parameter value) instead."*

```js
function removeWithHelpOfCharAt(str) {
  // the OP's code with the help of `charAt`.
  if (str.charAt(0) === 'p' && str.charAt(str.length - 1) === 'p') {

    return str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
  } else {
    return str;
  }
}
console.log(
  "removeWithHelpOfCharAt('pparallelepipedp') ...",
  removeWithHelpOfCharAt('pparallelepipedp')
);
console.log(
  "removeWithHelpOfCharAt('Pparallelepipedp') ...",
  removeWithHelpOfCharAt('Pparallelepipedp')
);

function removeWithHelpOfAt(str) {
  // the OP's code with the help of `at` ...
  // ... and a slightly changed way of returning the result.
  if (str.at(0) === 'p' && str.at(-1) === 'p') {

    str = str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(
  "removeWithHelpOfAt('pparallelepipedp') ...",
  removeWithHelpOfAt('pparallelepipedp')
);
console.log(
  "removeWithHelpOfAt('Pparallelepipedp') ...",
  removeWithHelpOfAt('Pparallelepipedp')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with slice:

```js
function remove(str) {
        if (str[0] === "p" && str.slice(-1) === "p") {
            return str.slice(1, -1);
        }
        
        return str
    }
    
console.log(remove("pparallelepipedp"));    // Returns: parallelepiped
console.log(remove("oparallelepipedp"))     // Returns: oparallelepipedp
console.log(remove("pparallelepipedo"));    // Returns: pparallelepipedo
```

You could also consider a regex validation. You can experiment with regex here: https://regex101.com/

In your case you could do:

```js
var regExp = /^p(.*?)p$/;

function remove(str) {
    return regExp.test(str) ? str.slice(1, -1) : str
}

console.log(remove('pparallelepipedp')); // Returns: parallelepiped
console.log(remove('oparallelepipedp')); // Returns: oparallelepipedp
console.log(remove('pparallelepipedo')); // Returns: pparallelepipedo
```

Comment: The above provided regex example could consider the usage of the case insensitive flag `i` in order to match `'p'` in its lower- and upper-case variant.

Answer (score -2):

The function indexOf returns the index of the item you pass as the param.

So str.indexOf(0) will try to find 0 in the str and return its index, if not found it'll return -1.

You can get more understanding of indexOf by playing with examples here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

So instead of using indexOf you need to use any other method through which you can access values on those specific indexes.

The code I wrote is to make things easier so we can easily perform our required actions

```
const remove = (str) => {
   // This will convert the string into an array
   // https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp
    str = str.split('');

    // Checking if value on first index is P
    if (str[0] == 'P'){
        // This function will remove the value on first index
        // https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp
        str.shift();
    }

    // Similarly check for if value on last index is P
    if (str[str.length - 1] == 'P') {
        // This will remove the value on last index
        // https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp
        str.pop();
    }

    // Other wise join the array back and send it as is
    // https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp
    return str.join('');
};
```

Comment: Rather than throwing a potentially alternative solution at the OP, why not take the time to explain what the problem is? That way they can learn something other than an unexplained black box of code.

Comment: This alternative contains elements that I haven't learned yet, so it's not exactly an option. Surely an explanation and a reference to the necessary documentation will help me more.

Comment: @Florence116 ... the above provided solution does the string conversion regardless of whether both conditions (starts **AND** ends with `'p'`) are met. Thus it converts/trims any side as soon as this side's condition is fulfilled. This is not what the OP was asking for. In addition the OP her/himself is looking for `'p'` and not its uppercase value like with the above implementation.